# Retrieving 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'layers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have the following code,  I am facing issue which I tried but couldn't figured it out to solve it.

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras import models, layers, Model, Input
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.models import load_model

def loaded_model():
   # load json and create model
   json_file = open('model_num.json', 'r')
   loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
   json_file.close()
   loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
   # load weights into new model
   loaded_model.load_weights("model_num.h5")
   print("Loaded model from disk")
   loaded_model.save('model_num.hdf5')
   loaded_model=load_model('model_num.hdf5')
def split_keras_model(model, index):
   layer_input_1 = Input(model.layers[0].input_shape[1:])
   x = layer_input_1
   for layer in model.layers[1:index]:
     x = layer(x)
   model1 = Model(inputs=layer_input_1, outputs=x)
   input_shape_2 = model.layers[index].get_input_shape_at(0)[1:]
   layer_input_2 = Input(shape=input_shape_2)
   x = layer_input_2
   for layer in model.layers[index:]:
     x = layer(x)
   model2 = Model(inputs=layer_input_2, outputs=x)
   return (model1, model2)
 m1,m2=split_keras_model(loaded_model(),3)
```

Error:

```
layer_input_1 = Input(model.layers[0].input_shape[1:])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'layers'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `loaded_model` function does not return anything. Add a line

```
return loaded_model
```

at the end.

... although I cannot see any reason why you should save the model and re-load it in order to return it in the *same* function; you should remove the last lines and actually change it to

```
def loaded_model():
   # load json and create model
   json_file = open('model_num.json', 'r')
   loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
   json_file.close()
   loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
   # load weights into new model
   loaded_model.load_weights("model_num.h5")
   print("Loaded model from disk")
   
   return loaded_model
```

If, as I guess, you want to save the model in `h5` format as a by-product of the function, you could keep the `loaded_model.save('model_num.hdf5')` line, but your last line `loaded_model=load_model('model_num.hdf5')` does not make any sense.